# Bulma - Column size is-half still applied on tablet mode with the is-desktop class

Tags: html, css, bulma

I have two columns (one with `is-half` class) that I want to "stack" (one on top of each other) on mobile AND tablet mode.

As from the documentation I have used `<div class="columns is-desktop"></div>`
But it is not working properly.. On tablet, columns are stacked but the first column, which has a `is-half` class, remains half sized.

Here's a snippet to illustrate the issue:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns is-desktop">
    <div class="column is-half">
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi nostrum voluptatum porro maiores animi dignissimos amet consectetur cumque sapiente eos, explicabo, accusamus modi mollitia labore corporis inventore eveniet esse quam?
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto alias necessitatibus doloremque magni minima nobis facere, quibusdam autem eveniet voluptatum amet explicabo voluptates, laudantium praesentium? Ab repellat eius doloremque labore.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or a [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mydnic/wtprmwsh/)

I want the `is-half` column to be fullwidth on tablet mode.

Comment: Please put a [mcve] **in the question**. Are you columns `is-half-desktop`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe there's only one column which is "is half", as in the fiddle.

Comment: And still *not* in the question, as required.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I updated the post title, I hope its ok that way ?

Comment: How does that help?! You still do not have an example in the body of the question as required. See [ask].

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought naming the classes + having a fiddle was enough sorry. I updated with an html example in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not** a bug. That's the **expected** behaviour.

`<div class="columns is-desktop"></div>`

has `display: block` until **desktop**

```
@media screen and (min-width:1024px){.columns.is-desktop{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex}}
```

`.is-half` has `width: 50%`

```
.column.is-half,.column.is-half-tablet{-webkit-box-flex:0;-ms-flex:none;flex:none;width:50%}
```

It's like

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.half {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="half">half</div>
<div>fullwidth</div>
```

between `768px` and `1024px`.

### Solution

(**Don't** set `.is-half`)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns is-desktop">
    <div class="column">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi nostrum voluptatum porro maiores animi dignissimos amet consectetur cumque sapiente eos, explicabo, accusamus modi mollitia labore corporis inventore eveniet esse quam?
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto alias necessitatibus doloremque magni minima nobis facere, quibusdam autem eveniet voluptatum amet explicabo voluptates, laudantium praesentium? Ab repellat eius doloremque labore.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to have other sizes, e.g. for **desktop**, use `.is-x-desktop`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.1/css/bulma.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="columns is-desktop">
    <div class="column is-8-desktop">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi nostrum voluptatum porro maiores animi dignissimos amet consectetur cumque sapiente eos, explicabo, accusamus modi mollitia labore corporis inventore eveniet esse quam?
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto alias necessitatibus doloremque magni minima nobis facere, quibusdam autem eveniet voluptatum amet explicabo voluptates, laudantium praesentium? Ab repellat eius doloremque labore.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change Class Name `is-half` to `is-half-desktop`

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="columns is-desktop">
        <div class="column is-half-desktop">
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi nostrum voluptatum porro maiores animi dignissimos amet consectetur cumque sapiente eos, explicabo, accusamus modi mollitia labore corporis inventore eveniet esse quam?
        </div>
        <div class="column is-half-desktop">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto alias necessitatibus doloremque magni minima nobis facere, quibusdam autem eveniet voluptatum amet explicabo voluptates, laudantium praesentium? Ab repellat eius doloremque labore.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wtprmwsh/2/

Comment: Thanks it works indeed ! A cleaner version even : https://jsfiddle.net/mydnic/wtprmwsh/4/

Comment: But isn't that a bug still ??

Comment: @ClémentRigo that's up to the package maintainer to decide; if you think it's not behaving as described, raise an issue on GitHub.